# Rocks DB WAL file has high disk usage

Tags: file, rocksdb

A sample rocksdb consumes ~75M of disk space out of this the WAL files (*.log) takes ~71M disk space. But the ls command shows the WAL file has actually very less byte consumption. I am interested to know why a WAL file that has very less content is taking so much disk space and also how to reduce this.

Output of du -h *

4.0K    000004.sst
**71M**     000006.log
4.0K    CURRENT
4.0K    IDENTITY
0       LOCK
128K    LOG
128K    LOG.old.1669987718576391
4.0M    MANIFEST-000005
8.0K    OPTIONS-000005
8.0K    OPTIONS-000008

Output of ls -lh
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris  966 Dec  2 18:58 000004.sst
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris   **40 **Dec  2 18:58 000006.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris   16 Dec  2 18:58 CURRENT
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris   37 Dec  2 18:57 IDENTITY
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris    0 Dec  2 18:57 LOCK
-rw-rw-r--. 1 polaris polaris  16K Dec  2 18:58 LOG
-rw-rw-r--. 1 polaris polaris  15K Dec  2 18:57 LOG.old.1669987718576391
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris  166 Dec  2 18:58 MANIFEST-000005
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris 4.5K Dec  2 18:57 OPTIONS-000005
-rw-r--r--. 1 polaris polaris 4.5K Dec  2 18:58 OPTIONS-000008

Sample program

```
#include <cassert>
#include <string>
#include <rocksdb/db.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    rocksdb::DB* db;
    rocksdb::Options options;
    options.create_if_missing = true;
    rocksdb::Status status =
    rocksdb::DB::Open(options, "/dev/shm/testdb", &db);
    assert(status.ok());
    // Insert value
    status = db->Put(rocksdb::WriteOptions(), "Test key", "Test value");
    assert(status.ok());
    // Read back value
    std::string value;
    status = db->Get(rocksdb::ReadOptions(), "Test key", &value);
    std::cout << value << '\n';
    assert(status.ok());
    assert(!status.IsNotFound());
    // Read key which does not exist
    status = db->Get(rocksdb::ReadOptions(), "This key does not exist", &value);
    assert(status.IsNotFound());
}
```

Any clue will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Note: If I manually copy the WAL file, then the copied file takes lesser disk space (4K as per du command)

Comment: you can always set the max wal size in the options

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat like using `reserve()` on an `std::vector`, RocksDB uses [`fallocate`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fallocate.2.html) on most of  its output files by default to minimize overall I/O costs in a long-running system. See the [`allow_fallocate`](https://github.com/facebook/rocksdb/blob/23af6786a997d3592e8a68f1a8d9e0699a6eae36/include/rocksdb/options.h#L848) option.

Comment: Thanks for this information, Yes on setting allow_fallocate to false, the initial WAL file sizes reduces very much.
As you mentioned the I/O cost will be higher without the pre-allocation, is there any benchmarking available to quantify the performance changes? Thanks again!